# ASP.NET APIController not returning data object in json

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm currently working on a little prototype with Angular 2 and ASP.NET.

According to angular.io documentation (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html) : "We shouldn't expect json() to return the heroes array directly. The server we're calling always wraps JSON results in an object with a dataproperty. We have to unwrap it to get the heroes. This is conventional web api behavior, driven by security concerns."

See this link : https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_AJAX_Security_Guidelines#Always_return_JSON_with_an_Object_on_the_outside

I built an APIController in ASP.NET to get a list of heros in JSON. Here is my code :

```
[DataContract]
public class Hero
{
    [DataMember]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }

    public Hero(string id, string name)
    {
        this.id= id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}    

public class HeroesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<Hero> Get()
    {
        return new Hero[] { new Hero("1", "TEST HERO #1"), 
                            new Hero("2", "TEST HERO #2")};
    }
}
```

But bizzarely, my ApiController is returning me this JSON response : 
[{"id":"1","name":"TEST HERO #1"}, {"id":"2","name":"TEST HERO #2"}]

instead of something like : 
{"data": [{"id":"1","name":"TEST HERO #1"}, {"id":"2","name":"TEST HERO #2"}]}

Do you have any ideas why ASP.NET Web api doesn't follow this security advice? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: WebAPI lets you control the entire response message, giving you control to either implement or not that pattern. It is completely up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC is returning exactly what you coded it to do.  Instead, you could return an anonymous class like

```
return new { data = new Hero[] { new Hero(...), new Hero(...) } };
```

While I'm on the subject, you might want to get in the habit of using the `HttpResponseMessage` pattern.  There's nothing explicitly wrong with the way you are doing things, but this allows a lot of fine-grain control over the response you are returning, including things like custom error messages and cache expirations.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    try
    {
        var result = new { data = new Hero[] { new Hero(...), new Hero(...) } };
        return Request.CreateResponse(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "My custom error message");
    }
}
```